# Windows application to upload files

Tags: c#, vb.net, file-upload

I need to make a windows application to upload files (jpg) that are on my computer to a web host. I have tried various codes I found on the web but none of them worked.
Does anyone have a working code to do this? Maybe in VB.NET or C#.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: -1...Are you using FTP? What have you tried? You need to be more clear if you want to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not revealing more details about your requirement, but still I'm providing couple of ideas on how do that based different scenarios.

First point: you need to be clear about your server side for receiving these files. Whether you want to activate ftp on server and provide ftp credentials to client to upload files to a particular folder. If not ftp then you should have your server listen to post requests from the client to upload files.

FTP: Here is the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/net_ftp_upload.aspx) to upload files from windows application to a FTP server.

Post: Here is the link for [post](http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post) way.